# css absolute position child height in parent with display table-cell not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position, absolute, tablecell

Quick question regarding positioning an absolute div in a parent display: table-cell in IE.

I have created a jsfiddle of the layout that I am trying to create and it works in chrome and firefox but in IE it breaks the **.list-container** absolute height of the child (which is se to to fill all space from the top 118px down) when inside of a parent with **display: table-cell** .

Is there any IE styling rules that I am missing to help it render the absolute child? Is this something that is possible in IE?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knw98qwh/27/)

```
html, body{ 
    height:100%; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0px; 
} 
.table{ 
   display : table; 
    width : 100%; 
    height : 100%; 
} 
.row{ 
    display : table-row; 
    width : 100%; 
    height : 100%; 
} 
.table-cell{ 
    height:100%; 
    width:50%; 
    border:1px solid #000; 
    display : table-cell; 
    position: relative; 
} 
.header{ 
    position:relative; 
    top:0px; 
    height:112px;  
    margin:0px; 
    border:3px solid blue; 
    background: rgba(0,0,230, .2); 
} 
.list-container{ 
    position:absolute; 
    top:118px; 
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px; 
    right:0px;  
    margin:0px; 
    overflow:auto; 
    overflow-x:hidden; 
    border:3px solid #CCC;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
} 

<body>
    <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <header class="header"></header>
            <div class="list-container">
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have noticed that the computed style in chrome and firefox for the parent div.table-cell is the full height of the table, but in the IE the div.table-cell has a height of the child relative header.header element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that in IE a table-cell only accepts the height from the child elements. If you add a wrapper div.table that has a styleof 100% with and height around the header.header and div.list-container it will give thew parent div.table-cell aheight of 100% of the parent table.

here is a jsfiddle showing the changes:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knw98qwh/32/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table-cell {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  height: 112px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 230, .2);
}
.list-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 118px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #CCC;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        <header class="header"></header>
        <div class="list-container">
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```